# Floating divs around and under an image

Tags: css, css-float

I am trying to design a page with a floating image to the left, a div to the right with its text and block elements flowing around the image, and then more div's below the image. See http://jsfiddle.net/BcjzK/3/ with this code:

```
.container {
    width:700px;
    border:solid 1px gray;
}
.content {
    width:460px;
    border:solid 1px red;
    margin-right:0px;
    margin-left:auto;
}
.extra-content {
    width:230px;
    border:solid 1px green;
}
img {
    float:left;
    border:solid 1px blue;
}
blockquote {
    border:solid 1px gray;
    width:30%;
    float:right;
}
```

and

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://hazelden.ca/sample.png" width="320" height="auto" />
    <div class="content">
        <p> Some content, some blockquotes and images</p>
    </div>
    <div class="extra-content">
        Some more text
    </div>
</div>
```

The large image will be set to a specific width, with its height set at "auto".

I can't get the green-bordered div (class="extra-content") to nestle in the space directly under the large image and still have the text and block elements in the red-bordered div (class="content") flow properly. I've tried multiple combinations of clear: in various elements and re-ordering div's.

I'm hoping it's something simple I'm not seeing.

Comment: Have you tried having img and content both as float:left; so they just flow, and then adding the extra-content, so it should just go underneath? but make sure you also add a clear:right; on the content

Comment: Because the combined width of the image and content div is wider than the container div, floating the content div just forces it below the image. No combination of float: and clear: seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working in your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/BcjzK/4/

Because of the way div layouts work, its always going to start the green div below the red one if it comes after the red one in the HTML code unless you put it in a parent container that encapsules the entire left side.

As a fix I made another container div that would hold both the img and the green div and then floated that container left.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="imgContainer">
    <img src="http://hazelden.ca/sample.png" alt="Some Image" width="320" height="auto" />
    <div class="extra-content">
        Text
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
...
```

CSS:

```
.container {
width:700px;
border:solid 1px gray;

}

.imgContainer{

 float: left;

}
.content {
 width:460px;
 border:solid 1px red;
 margin-right:0px;
 margin-left:auto;

}
.extra-content {
 width:230px;
 border:solid 1px green;
}
img {

 border:solid 1px blue;
}
blockquote {
 border:solid 1px gray;
 width:30%;
 float:right;
}
```

EDIT:

I noticed that the imgContainer box forces your content text to change position slightly to accommodate it's presence. if you want the content text to lay out precisely the same as before use this:

```
.imgContainer{  
 float: left;
 height: 450px;
 overflow: visible;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BcjzK/5/

You can even get the content text under the pic as close as it is on the side by changing the height property of imgContainer to 430px.

http://jsfiddle.net/BcjzK/6/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your input! The only problem now is that as more content is added to the green div and it grows taller, the text in the content div doesn't wrap under the image until it clears the green div.

Comment: it should work if you use the code from the second or third link to jsfiddle i posted. setting the imgContainer height to a fixed amount and then setting the overflow: visible property seems to do what you want it to. This is fiddle 6 with a bunch of text in the green box: http://jsfiddle.net/BcjzK/7/